# Iterate Over a tuple

Tags: scala, iterator

I need to implement a generic method that takes a tuple and returns a Map 
Example :

```
val tuple=((1,2),(("A","B"),("C",3)),4)
```

I have been trying to break this tuple into a list :

```
val list=tuple.productIterator.toList
Scala>list: List[Any] = List((1,2), ((A,B),(C,3)), 4)
```

But this way returns List[Any] .

I am trying now to find out how to iterate over the following tuple ,for example :

```
((1,2),(("A","B"),("C",3)),4)
```

in order to loop over each element 1,2,"A",B",...etc. **How could I do this kind of iteration over the tuple**

Comment: I don´t understand "returns a Map". You want something like a `Seq` of all elements of any tuple and subtuples?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about? :

```
def flatProduct(t: Product): Iterator[Any] = t.productIterator.flatMap {
  case p: Product => flatProduct(p)
  case x => Iterator(x)
}
val tuple = ((1,2),(("A","B"),("C",3)),4)
flatProduct(tuple).mkString(",") // 1,2,A,B,C,3,4
```

Ok, the `Any`-problem remains. At least that´s due to the return type of `productIterator`.

Comment: I have no idea but for some reason I look at ur post intentionally  again after months and noticed that ur way does fix my issue properly. I guess that when u post ur answer I couldn't get what Product refers to . Now it makes sense . Thx Peter :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of tuples, use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0) data structures like HList.  You can have generic processing, and also don't lose type information.

The only problem is that documentation isn't very comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

```
tuple.productIterator map { 
   case (a,b) => println(a,b) 
   case (a) => println(a)
}
```

Comment: hi ,but this methodology won't be generic . Is there anyway to iterate over each variable of the tuple !!   For example ((1,2),(("A","B"),("C",3)),4) == > Required result : 1 , 2, "A" , "B" , "c" ,...4

Comment: You can modify the case as you want. For example:
case (a:Tuple2[_, _ ],b:Tuple2[ _, _ ]) => do something with a and b.
You can also match on Tuples with specific types.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. tranform is a tuple consists of dataframes

```
def apply_function(a: DataFrame) = a.write.format("parquet").save("..." + a + ".parquet")
transform.productIterator.map(_.asInstanceOf[DataFrame]).foreach(a => apply_function(a))
```