# Flatten an element in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have data like this in an RDD:

```
RDD[((Int, Int, Int), ((Int, Int), Int))]
```

as:

```
(((9,679,16),((2,274),1)), ((250,976,13),((2,218),1)))
```

I want output as :

```
((9,679,16,2,274,1),(250,976,13,2,218,1))
```

After Joining 2 rdds with:

```
val joinSale = salesTwo.join(saleFinal)
```

I got that result set. I tried the following code.

```
joinSale.flatMap(x => x).take(100).foreach(println)
```

I have tried map/flatMap but couldn't do it. Any ideas how to implement a scenario like this ? Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Tuple doesn't have a flatten method. However you can use `productIterator` to flatten it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289408/iterate-over-a-tuple However this is really ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with pattern matching in scala. Simply wrap your tuple modification logic within a map similar to the below:

```
val mappedJoinSale = joinSale.map { case ((a, b, c), ((d, e), f)) => (a, b, c, d, e, f) }
```

Using your example, we have:

```
scala> val example = sc.parallelize(Array(((9,679,16),((2,274),1)), ((250,976,13),((2,218),1))))
example: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((Int, Int, Int), ((Int, Int), Int))] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:12

scala> val mapped = example.map { case ((a, b, c), ((d, e), f)) => (a, b, c, d, e, f) }
mapped: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)] = MappedRDD[1] at map at <console>:14

scala> mapped.take(2).foreach(println)
...
(9,679,16,2,274,1)
(250,976,13,2,218,1)
```

Comment: woow, now I feel stupid .. I did implement the map case a while back .. well i might have forgotten .. anyways thank you ..

Comment: @Achillies57 no worries, we all forget things :)

Answer (score 3):

You could also create generic tuple flattener using marvelous [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library as follows:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.tuple
trait LowLevelFlatten extends Poly1 {
  implicit def anyFlat[T] = at[T](x => Tuple1(x))
}

object concat extends Poly2 {
  implicit def atTuples[T1, T2](implicit prepend: tuple.Prepend[T1, T2]): Case.Aux[T1, T2, prepend.Out] =
    at[T1,T2]((t1,t2) => prepend(t1,t2))
}

object flatten extends LowLevelFlatten {
  implicit def tupleFlat[T, M](implicit
                               mapper: tuple.Mapper.Aux[T, flatten.type, M],
                               reducer: tuple.LeftReducer[M, concat.type]
                                ): Case.Aux[T, reducer.Out] =
    at[T](t => reducer(mapper(t)))
}
```

Now in any code where `import shapeless._` exists you could use it as

```
joinSale.map(flatten)
```