# reduce key, list(values) to key, value using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi i am new to apache spark and scala. I am trying to convert 
`Array(('a',1), ('b',(1,1)), ('c',1))` to `Array(('a',1), ('b',2), ('c',1))`

Could you please help me in conversion.

Comment: Do you maybe mean ` Array((a,List(1)), (b,List(1,1)), (c,List(1)))`? If not, what is the type of you input supposed to be?

Comment: And there's nothing Spark there - all Arrays (and maybe Lists). Please be clearer.

Comment: What does `(b,(2))` mean?  Wouldn't `(b,2)` be better?

Comment: updated my question. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of concrete types in the question I have made an assumption that the values in your array are Char and Int tuples respectively. Here is how we can transform to the desired output:

```
scala> val a = Array(('a',1), ('b',(1,1)), ('c',1))
a: Array[(Char, Any)] = Array((a,1), (b,(1,1)), (c,1))

scala> a map { case (first, second) => (first, second match { case p: Product =>  Tuple1(p.productIterator.map(_.asInstanceOf[Int]).reduce(_ + _)); case _=> second }) }
res27: Array[(Char, Any)] = Array((a,1), (b,(2,)), (c,1))
```

Basically we can traverse the elements in a Tuple using a productIterator. We also need to map each value to an Integer so so to compute the sum.

Also have a look at this question: [Iterate Over a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289408/iterate-over-a-tuple)